How can I disable line wrap in the official MySQL Docker image CLI?
Query results with many columns are difficult to read when the width surpasses the size of your screen and the lines wrap and stack under each other. A common solution to this issue is the use of a pager, like Less or More, but the Docker MySQL image does not come with a pager, nor does it come with the command line tools to install a pager.
I've tried to install the pagers less and more using a variety of package installers, and none of them have worked on the command line:
bash-4.4# yum install less
bash: yum: command not found

bash-4.4# apt-get install less
bash: apt-get: command not found

bash-4.4# dnf install less
bash: dnf: command not found

Is there a way to install Less with the official Docker MySQL image, or at least get a package manager so I can install it myself?
Here is a link to the MySQL Docker image I'm using.

Is this a MySQL problem or a yum problem?

@NicoHaase The accepted answer shows that microdnf is the package manager for this MySQL container, and a new pager, Less, can be installed to disable line wrap for tables with widths greater than the terminal window. I would say that this is a MySQL problem that was solved through finding the appropriate package manager, microdnf.

If we look at the image with podman inspect (or docker inspect or any other container image inspection) we see:
          "Labels": null,
          "Annotations": {
               "com.docker.official-images.bashbrew.arch": "amd64",
               "org.opencontainers.image.base.digest": "sha256:94e5211ff5e083086ab82506121da739752da964a8d7a1ba98624dc7ac68c76f",
               "org.opencontainers.image.base.name": "oraclelinux:9-slim",

....
               {
                    "created": "2024-07-22T22:36:10Z",
                    "created_by": "RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux; \tmicrodnf install -y \"mysql-community-server-minimal-$MYSQL_VERSION\";

So oraclelinux:9-slim is the base and microdnf is the package installer.
Is it possible to install less with it?
$ podman run --rm  mysql microdnf install less
Downloading metadata...
Downloading metadata...
Downloading metadata...
Downloading metadata...
Package                  Repository            Size
Installing:                                        
 less-590-4.el9_4.x86_64 ol9_baseos_latest 179.3 kB
Transaction Summary:
 Installing:        1 packages
 Reinstalling:      0 packages
 Upgrading:         0 packages
 Obsoleting:        0 packages
 Removing:          0 packages
 Downgrading:       0 packages
Downloading packages...
Running transaction test...
Installing: less;590-4.el9_4;x86_64;ol9_baseos_latest
Complete.

Yes it is.
